# Подключить cURL к проекту vc++ 2012 express (err 0xc000007b)

Tags: visual-c++, curl, библиотеки

У меня Win7x64 и *Visual Studio 2012 Express*.

1. Cкачал вот эту версию cURL: Win32 - MSVC 7.18.0.
2. В свойствах проекта указал пути к каталогам c `.lib` и `.h` файлами.
3. В компоновщике добавил `libcurl.lib`.
4. Кинул `libcurl.dll` в папку `Debug` с `exe` файлом. (Иначе программа говорит, что не может его найти).

Вот код `main.cpp` (взято с сайта с примерами):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");

    /* Выполнение запроса, res будет содержать код возврата */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Проверка на ошибки */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* Очистка */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Вроде всё компилируется, но при запуске вылазит это:

> Ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc000007b). Для выхода из приложения нажмите кнопку "ОК".

Как это можно исправить?

---

***UPD:*** Когда компилирую в x64:

> ```
> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешённый внешний символ __imp_curl_easy_strerror в функции main
> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешённый внешний символ __imp_curl_easy_init в функции main
> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешённый внешний символ __imp_curl_easy_setopt в функции main
> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешённый внешний символ __imp_curl_easy_perform в функции main
> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешённый внешний символ __imp_curl_easy_cleanup в функции main
> error LNK1120: неразрешённых внешних элементов: 5
> ```

Comment: А запустить под отладчиком пробовали? Какая строка приводит к ошибке?

Comment: Скомпилировал это под линуксом. Все скомпилировалось и работало как ожидается ( `curl_easy_perform` возвращает 0). Подозреваю, что библиотека скомпилирована с поддержкой многопоточности, а Ваш код - нет.

Comment: @VlaD, curl = curl_easy_init();

Comment: @KoVadim, как включить поддержку?

Comment: при компиляции 64битным оно так и должно быть - библиотека то у Вас 32битная.

А вот включить поддержку - это в настройках проекта ищите - опции `/MD` `/MT` и [играйтесь с ними](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757418/should-i-compile-with-md-or-mt).

Comment: @KoVadim, не помогло :(

Comment: В инете где-то ещё предлагалось использовать для нахождения неполадки утилиту Dependency Walker. Открыл ею свой exe и она вывела это:
> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.      
>Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.  
>Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.  
>Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Не совсем понятно, что значат эти ошибки, но кажется, что дело в x32 библиотеках.